# form submission on same page

Tags: html

JavaScript:

```
function CreateMsg() {
    var MsgDOM = document.getElementById("MSG");
    MsgDOM.innerHTML = "Hello, " + document.forms[0].FNAME.value  + " " + document.forms[0].LNAME.value  + ". You're sex is " + document.forms[0].GENDER.value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<FORM NAME="DUH">
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=FNAME>
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=LNAME>
    <SELECT NAME="GENDER">
        <OPTION VALUE="Male">Male</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="Female">Female</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    <BR><BR>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="javascript:CreateMsg();"/>
    <BR><BR>
    <SPAN ID="MSG">&nbsp;</SPAN>
</FORM>
```

Comment: I'll just take a guess. Your JS function is not working and you will need to use ID attribute instead of NAME while naming your INPUTs in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the JavaScript method like this -

```
function CreateMsg() {
    var MsgDOM = document.getElementById("MSG");
    var duhForm = document.forms[0];
    MsgDOM.innerHTML = "Hello, " + duhForm.FNAME.value  + " " + duhForm.LNAME.value  + ". You're sex is " + duhForm.GENDER.value;
    duhForm.target="_self"; // or _top or _parent or _blank
    duhForm.action="PleaseAskTheQuestion.do";
    duhForm.submit();
}
```

*mu is too short* has already submitted the form on the same page, but server is too busy; no donuts for you. :-)